# How to record only the last 10 seconds of audio using AVAudioRecorder?

Tags: iphone, avaudiorecorder, avaudiosession

This might be a very simple request so apologies if it is.

I'm using AVAudioRecorder to record sound from the iphone's mic. Currently I'm saving this to a file. The recording is only stopped once the user taps a button and is then played back.

My question is how would I get it so that the audio recorder only saves the last 10 seconds of sound?

I know I could probably get the player to only play from the last 10 seconds but I don't want the recorded audio file to get huge. I'd prefer to just record the last 10 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the AVAudioRecorder API.  It can't do what you want.  Use the Audio Queue API (or maybe the RemoteIO Audio Unit) to record samples to a circular buffer 10 seconds long (that's less than 1 megabyte in size).  Then unroll this circular buffer when writing the samples out to a .wav file following a WAVE/RIFF file header.

Comment: Hey hotpaw2, thanks for the advice on this. sorry to be a pain but before I playback the audio I also will have to modify its pitch. can I use the AudioQueue to do this or should I use openAL?

Comment: Only the OpenAL API currently contains a built-in resampler.  Or you could write your own resampling code, and use the Audio Queue API.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand audio enough to write my own resampler so I think I'll just use openAL :) Thanks again for your advice hotpaw2